# How to have a user who can 'su' to another user but not allowed to 'su' root

Tags: ubuntu, debian, su, pam

In my server, I have 2 groups: `ssh-users` and `su-users`

`ssh-users` hold users I ssh to the box with. User `sshu` is a member of `ssh-users`. Once logged in to the server, I want `ssh-users` members to be able to perform su to an user of `su-users` group **but don't want them** to be able to `su root`.

`su-users` hold users who can do core work and want them to have rights to perform `su` to root or any user.

How can I achieve this on Debian?

I tried the `pam_wheel.so` module in `/etc/pam.d/su` but any group I mention there are allowed su to root.

I also tried this but with no effect: https://superuser.com/a/398087/119486

Comment: Having a group `A` whose members can log in as members of group `B`, having group `B`'s members able to log in as `root`, _and_ preventing members of group `A` from becoming root are not all possible. What are you [really trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here?

Comment: @BlacklightShining I am trying to create a few users (group `ssh-users`) with very restricted perms on the machine. If they need to manage the web application, they need to have the rights to do so. These rights are given to `su-users`. Doing this primarily from the security and control point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way `su` works by default. All you need to do is make sure that your `root` password is secure. To `su` to *any* user, you need to know that user's password. So, if your `ssh-users` don't have root's password, they won't be able to switch to root. As long as they have the target user's pass they will be able to `su` to that user.

I don't understand what else you need.

Comment: You are right. But I want to block access to root in the permissions also. That's because it's a small startup. I feel that it's achievable using PAM but I am still a novice at it.

Comment: @EthanCollins I don't know if that is possible (it may well be) I am, however, pretty sure it's not worth it. The only way they can su to root is if they know root's password. Just make sure they don't.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, and I get to feel it's not worth the time. I would ask you another thing I am struggling with: for a 4 member team, what all user accounts should I create and permissions to provide for better security -- is just 4 user accounts with ssh-rights and another user for web application to run enough? This is what I am thinking now, creating these 4+1 normal users (app is a normal user with shell) and have only those members concerned about the app know the app user's password. (PS: I am not a sysadmin, bear with my inexperience)

Comment: @EthanCollins sounds good to me but I'm not a sysadmin either so I don't really know. I would recommend posting a question about that. Either here or (perhaps better) on [unix.se] where a lot more sysadmin types hang out.

Comment: Here's a good explanation of pam_listfile and PAM in general, which I found helpful: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=165226&seqNum=10